# Trying for loop for a list of single column value from a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to perform some thing like. TargetInfoID will returns list of ids. Based on that list, i want to rotate a loop. I tried like this. but in @id it is storing only first record details. not list.

```
    Declare @id int;
    select @id=TargetInfoID from TargetsTable --it returns list of ids       
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
    WHILE @cnt < Count(@id))
    BEGIN
      PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP';
      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
   END;

    PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP';
  GO
```

Comment: Look up cursors.

Comment: Why do you want to loop at all? SQL is a set based language, so the last thing you should be doing it looping. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: In that print statements i want to perform some action. Based on the list of ids which i'll get from targettable.

Comment: `PRINT` statements can't perform "actions". They literally do what they function is called, it prints an output message. It can't do change data, assign variables, etc. Again, what are you *really* trying to achieve.

Comment: using cursors I achieved the looping. Thank you for your suggestion @stickybit

Comment: This still doesn't explain what you want to do! Even if the loop works for now, it will lead to really bad performance with increasing number of records. As already mentioned by Larnu, SQL is set based - you will be better off overthinking the desired result and modifying your process accordingly.